# How to know which Tabbar Menu Clicked

Tags: ios, tabbar

I have an `UITabBarController` which is linked to 5 viewcontrollers as shown in the figure bellow.

In my opening screen, I have register page, if user does not register then I do not want to allow user to see any content of Rewards and Offers ViewController.

Whenever user clicks on tabbarviewcontroller, I would like to generate an `UIAlertView` that displays either register or cancel.

My question is when the user clicks on the Rewards or Offers, how should I know which tabbar menu clicked to generate `UIAlertView` ?

I am using storyboard. I have a `tabbarcontroller` and a custom class of this tabbarcontroller. Header file is as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainHarvestGrillTabBarViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarDelegate>

@end
```

I would like to know how should I have access which tab is clicked.

I have implemented the following code, but it always return o no matter which tab is clicked.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    NSUInteger index = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    NSLog(@"index %lu",(unsigned long)index);
    // Recenter the slider (this application does not accumulate multiple filters)
    // Redraw the view with the new settings
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you created properties for the 5 view controllers to access them directly (i.e. `self.firstViewController, self.secondViewController` etc..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check which tab was selected using the tab bar's `didSelectItem` protocol method but this won't prevent the view controller from being displayed. Instead you can make use of the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and implement the `shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method. So then you would check the selected view controller and act accordingly. Below is an example for preventing the user selecting the Rewards tab:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ([tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] == viewController) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        return NO;

    }
    return YES;
}
```

You'd place this in your tab bar controller class. You also need to add `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` to your header file and set `self.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sooper. Your logic is right. However if you check my updated question, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Use `NSUInteger index = [tabBar.items indexOfObject:item];` instead.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Spooer, it worked very well, appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

To grab the index of the selected tab item:

```
NSUInteger index = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;//The index of the view controller associated with the currently selected tab item.
```

Or if you would like to grab the actual viewController associated with the selection you could do this:

```
id yourViewController = [self.tabBarController selectedViewController];//The view controller associated with the currently selected tab item
```